# Load page specific script in a .js file with code from all pages

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use the same JS file for all pages, but I have specific code per page. Which design pattern should I use to prevent code conflict and having to add script tags in my page just to call the specific code?

Example of what I usually do:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var page = new PageA();
page.init();
</script>
```

I'm looking for an alternative for the last script tag, as I think it may be unnecessary.

Comment: Why do you use one file for all pages? In that case you'll load too much unnecessary code and it'll slow down first page loading. I would recommend you to take a look at any module loader like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) or [StealJS](http://javascriptmvc.com/docs/stealjs.html).

Comment: As an alternative to that, let your script figure out itself what page it is on – for example by giving the `body` element of each page a specific id, that the script’s general init function can look at and then decide what to do.

Comment: @Kiril I`m using just one file to decrease the number of server requests. I`m affraid that RequireJS would add server requests (but asynchronous).

Comment: @JulianoNunesSilvaOliveira, most of loaders are also able to minify and join JS modules. And just imagine: you have 10 pages each requires 1MB of JS. With your approach you'll load 10MB of code. But user may visit only 1-2 pages. As a result - 8MB of unnecessary data. If you want only one JS file - try to convert your site into single-page application. Read [more](http://www.johnpapa.net/spa/)

Comment: @Kiril I`ll check the ability to minify and join the JS modules from this JS libraries. This helps me solving the problem with round tripping.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this if you want to bundle all the javascript into one file although I don't recomend it because you will be loading way more javascript than necessary.
The only reason you can do this is because HTML lets you make your own attributes that start with: data-

```
if(document.querySelector('html').getAttribute('data-document-name') == "document1"){
    // Code for document1
    alert("You are document1");
};
if(document.querySelector('html').getAttribute('data-document-name') == "document2"){
    // Code for document2 
    alert("You are document2");
};
```

This is what it looks like on the html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="yourScriptFile.js"> </script>
</body>
</html>
```